# The IEC 61000-3-2 standard

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-design, power-electronics

Could anyone explains to me how to interpret the table of IEC 61000-3-2 standard given in wikipedia through the following link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61000-3-2

For example:

| Harmonic order | Limits class A (A) |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1.08 |
| 3 | 2.30 |
| 4 | 0.43 |

What is the relationship of the class limit to the Harmonic order? What is the link between **2** as a harmonic order and **1.08** as a class A limits?

Comment: Second harmonic current introduced by a Class A appliance must be less than 1.08Amps. Etc. There's no mathematical relationship, but an empirical determination that currents above this may cause harm (such as interference)

Comment: Are you looking for some mathematical relationship? IEC specs are designed by committee and that usually means math relationships get compromised.

Comment: [A Practical Guide for EN 61000-3-2 - Limits for harmonic current emissions](https://www.emcstandards.co.uk/files/61000-3-2_mains_harmonics.pdf).  [Main site](https://www.emcstandards.co.uk/a-practical-guide-for-en-61000-3-2-limits-for-h)

Comment: so the 1.08 is the maximum amplitude of the second harmonic of the current signal and the 2.3 is the maximum amplitude of the third harmonic and so on, that's it ??

Comment: Yes, with the unit being Amps. (Some other classes use other units as in the linked Wiki).